# JavaScript Boolean Values

Tags: javascript

Am I setting up the boolean values right? Because it's not working for me. Basically, on my website, I only want one alert message popping up (starting with the earliest pop up to the later one) until all fields have been checked.

---

Example:

1) Validate Pizza Size (user selected a pizza size)

2) Validate Toppings (user did not select a pizza size)

3) Validate Text Area (user did not select a pizza size)

Result: Only pop up #2 comes up stating "Select Jalapeno!" and not pop up #3 (if that makes any sense)

---

Here is my JavaScript:

http://pastebin.com/6c2cxU5X

Comment: Walk through your code in a debugger. Also, put the code in the question. Also, give your question a descriptive title.

Comment: Your JavaScript looks more like a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Javascript...

```
pizzaSizeElement.value = ""
```

To compare, should be:

```
pizzaSizeElement.value == ""
```

or if you want to ensure what your comparing is of the same type (string) then:

```
pizzaSizeElement.value === ""
```